# MVC3 Javascript alert and Redirect

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

How can I have a javascript alert in MVC 3 such that I would have an alert before I redirect to another page. Here's my code :

```
Content("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Updated Successfully!');</script>");
return Redirect("ViewDataFiles?catid=" + catid);
```

It doesn't make the alert and it redirects to the specified page. How can I both have the javascript alert and the MVC redirection ?

Comment: Why do you want to show a message using JavaScript? When JS is disabled (not a rare occasion due to http://noscript.net/), the user won't get any message.

Comment: Why not just create an action that runs on success and then re-direct after displaying a popup for example?

Comment: @Rob What can be another way to have a client side message ?

Comment: @Arjel What about just printing the message in the page (temporary stored in a session)? E.g. in the same way that http://userscripts.org/ does. Or, if a transition page is required, add `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; url=finalpage.here">` in the head of the page (all without JavaScript).

Answer (score 1):

This works successfully:

```
return Content("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Something going wrong!');window.location = '/Labels/ViewLabelTypeIndex';</script>");
```

Answer (score 0):

you probably can do something like this..
but this aint what i recommend.

```
JavaScriptResult("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Updated Successfully!');
window.location = "YOUR_NEW_LOCATION";
</script>");
```

instead you should probably send a ajax request and show the updated message and take the user to next page..